# Closing Slack Modal from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, modal-dialog, slack, slack-api

I'm having trouble closing a Slack Modal from an AWS Lambda in Python, getting a "We had some trouble connecting. Try again?" message. I have read several alternatives about returning an empty 200 ok message, but nothing seems to work. Currently, my AWS Lambda return looks like this:

```
return
    {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": ""
    }
```

Any idea what is wrong with it?

[image: We had some trouble connecting. Try again?]

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this. Not sure why, and it's probably overkill, but this works for me. I changed my return statement by creating the dictionary before the actual return, and then returning the dictionary, like this:

```
returnobject={
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "",
    "response_action": "clear"
}
return returnobject
```

If someone can explain to me why this works and not my previous attempts I would thank it a lot.

Comment: bc you added `response_action` per https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#close_all_views

Comment: thanks, but I did try that inside of the return statement , which is why I’m confused ¯\_(ツ)_/¯